# Cannot connect to 802.11b/g/n Wi-Fi with Intel 3945ABG card on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, 802.11n

Recently I've installed a new MikroTik router with 802.11b/g/n Wi-Fi (WPA2-PSK AES). All the client computers but one had no problem connecting to it. The one is old Amilo Pro V3545 with Intel 3945ABG Wi-Fi card and Windows XP SP3 installed.

The card definitely works with this router setup, because when I booted up from a live Ubuntu OS on this computer, I had no problem connecting to the Wi-Fi.

But when I'm in Windows XP and I try to connect to the Wi-Fi network, it ends with "unable to connect error". Connecting to any other Wi-Fi from Windows XP is without any problems.

I've tried to install new drivers directly from Intel's website: Wireless_15.8.0.x32 and I tried to connect with their Wi-Fi utility - It worked for once! But when I rebooted the computer, I'm unable to connect again. I tried reinstalling the Drivers (repair and also full uninstall and install), but it won't work again. I also tried disabling and enabling the device via Device Manager. Won't help.

Here is a dump of the information from Intel troubleshooter:

```
#Event,Source,Time,Error Severity,Domain,User,Description
1,SupplicantPlugin,09/12/2013 15:56:19,Information,Security,SYSTEM,<State> disconnected (nd3q2p)
2,SupplicantPlugin,09/12/2013 15:56:19,Information,Security,SYSTEM,DriverOIDCB- WARNING! Ignoring set event when not associated
3,EvtEngine,09/12/2013 15:56:10,Success,EvTrace,SYSTEM,Service queue reset done.
```

Do you have any recommendation what else should I do?

Comment: Will it connect with no security or possibly WEP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the culprit!

It was a "WPA2 EAP" enabled Wi-Fi security settings on Mikrotik router, which appareantly Windows XP SP3 cannot handle. When I disabled WPA2 and I am using only "WPA2 PSK", everything works great.

Attached image should help you if you are experiencing the same problem.

Leave it as displayed here:

[image]

Comment: WPA2 EAP is typically used in Enterprise installs.  It usually wants  specific hardware on both sides or possibly a RADIUS server.  XP should work with WPA2 EAP if all pieces are in place.